# Combobox options and Calendar are hiding behind the table in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox, overflow

We have created a custom table using Lightning web Component. In that table some of columns are of picklist(combo- box). when we click the that combo box Options are hiding behind the footer.
How can we overflow it so that options will come on top of footer.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a common behavior with lwc components.
So far, we have managed this by setting an overflow to the container, or by modifying the height of the container when elements of this nature are clicked. there are not too many options to work around this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For some lwc components you can set the `z-index` value which basically set the cmp to more foreground or more background. Open developer console in your browser and try to play with the `z-index` value. For example here

[image]

you can see that the `z-index` is defined by the css var `--slds-c-popover-position-zindex`, try in your cmp css style to set this variable to desired value. It should override the value defined in the standard lwc component. Here is more [info](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropdown-alignment="auto".
Combobox will calculate position based on the available screen size.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

One option is to replace your combobox with the standard HTML select tag. See my answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/353192/87694) on a similar question.